# Point of tangency between plane and sphere

Tags: solid-geometry

How can one find the point of tangency between a plane and a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$? The equations of the plane and the sphere are $x + y + z - 5 = 0$ and $(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z+1)^2 = 3$ respectively.

I realized that the distance between the point of tangency and the center of the sphere must equal its radius, but setting this constraint up just yielded the equation $x + y + z - 5 = 0$. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersect the line (1/2/-1) + t (1/1/1) with the plane.

The point (1/2/-1) is the mid-point of the sphere. The normal vector of the plane has the same direction as the line between the mid-point of the sphere and the point of tangency.

Note that the distance of the sphere-mid-point from the plane is $\sqrt{3}$, so the plane indeed is a tangency plane.

Comment: Oh gosh it was that easy, can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a point on both the sphere and the plane where the gradient $\nabla f$ of 
$$f(x,y,z)=(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z+1)^2$$
is parallel to (ie. a constant multiple of) $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle$. This leads to the following set of 5 equations in 4 unknowns.
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 2 (x-1)=\lambda  \\
 2 (y-2)=\lambda  \\
 2 (z+1)=\lambda  \\
 (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z+1)^2=3 \\
 x+y+z=5 \\
\end{array}
$$

This is an overdetermined system because it's unusual for there to be a solution.  In this particular case, there *is* a solution, namely $x=2$, $y=3$, $z=0$, and $\lambda=2$, as you can easily verify.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I know nothing about so called gradients. We were assigned to solve it using fundamental knowledge about analytic geometry and linear algebra. By the way, how did you make that 3D-plot?

Comment: If you're parametrizing lines in 3D, you can't be far off from the gradient! I made the image with Mathematica.